# ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated stops when only one element is invisible?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to wait for a few loading spinners to disappear. So I use a wait for ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated , for example:

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 120)).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("Spinner")));
```

However, the wait ends while some loading spinners still exist on the screen. It seems that when the first spinner found by this query becomes invisible, the wait stops.

Is there any way to wait for *all* elements to become invisible, other than a custom condition?

Comment: What else have you tried? Did you try `ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfAllElements(elements)`?

Comment: It is not guaranteed that new elements will not appear during the wait, so just searching for them once and then using `invisibilityOfAllElements(elements)` won't work.

Comment: I have implemented the custom condition, but I wonder if there is an accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can try following if all Spinners have same class as"spinner"

```
 (new WebDriverWait(driver, 120)).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfAllElements(driver.findElements(By.className("Spinner"))));
```

Comment: But this would find the elements with the class `Spinner` once, at the start of the wait. What if a new one got added during the wait?